# Getting single data from collection in iron router

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

When I put this code in the middle of the JS it works:

```
  var imageVar = sites.findOne({name: 'juego'}).createdBy;
  console.log(imageVar);
```

It returns the Id of the creator which is what I want. However, when I put it in iron router I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdBy' of undefined` error

What I put is:

```
    var imageVar = sites.findOne({name: 'juego'}).createdBy;
    return {
    im: Imagess.findOne({'metadata.createdBy':imageVar}),
    }
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, like you say it work outsite the route this is happening because you are trying to load the data when the collection isnt ready, try with

```
    waitOn:function(){
       return Meteor.subscribe('Example')
   }
```

To proove this put a simple `console.log` without the createdBy  and use `.fetch()` it should return

```
   console.log(Imagess.find().fetch())
   output []// empty array
```

**NOTE** in order to get the waitOn function working you need use a `loadingTemplate` in the `Router.configure`